# New range with old time wiring.the aluminum has 2 jacketed wires and 1 raw aluminum and the range requires red black and white

Tags: wiring

I have 3 cdrs 6 aluminum wire on a 40 amp breaker and my new range reguires 3 wire 6 to a 50.Is there anything i can do temporarily to use my range.

Comment: Could you give us the model number of the new oven? #6 is normally good for 50A.

Comment: The bare aluminum wire.  Is it a single wire, or is it a mesh that wraps around the hot wires?

Comment: What make and model is the new range, and how many kW is it? Also, can you post photos of the inside of the box for the existing range receptacle?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. But, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.